# How to disable a textbox if a select option has some value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have a form with some input type I want to hide ins-date text box if AMC or 4C is selected

```
<form>
   <select class="con-type">
      <option>AMC</option>
      <option>4C</option>
      <option>None</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" id="i-date" class="ins-date />
   <input type="text" id="w-date" class="wexp-date" />
</form>
```

My JQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.con-type').change(function () {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'AMC'||$(this).find('option:selected').text() == '4c') {
            $('.ins-date').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#ins-date').prop('disabled', '')
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements has always val() attribute not text().

So you should use val() of select box like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.con-type').change(function () {

        var select_value = $(this).val();

        if (select_value == 'AMC' || select_value == '4c') {
            $('.ins-date').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.ins-date').prop('disabled', '')
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yap got it..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#select').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 2 )
    {
        $('#text').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});

<select id="select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="text" >
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rj3k62Le/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, you're only missing a closed double quote in

```
<input type="text" id="i-date" class="ins-date />
```

and mixing class name with id selector in

```
$('#ins-date').prop('disabled', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.con-type').change(function () {
                if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'AMC' || $(this).find('option:selected').text() == '4c') {
                    $('.ins-date').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                    $('.ins-date').prop('disabled', '')
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**change else part id 'is-date' as a class** its work..!!